# Simple Clock Division

Tags: clock

I am working on a clock project that will use a 32768 Hz temperature compensated crystal oscillator chip, likely a DS3231. I plan to bring that frequency down to 1 Hz using flipflop frequency division ICs. However I do not want the 1 Hz signal to be 50% duty cycle, I want something more like 25% - 12.5% as seen below.

I would like to use this 25% 1 Hz signal to pulse a very small solenoid to advance the clock movement, and I do not want to waste battery power by having the solenoid energized 50% of the time when it only needs to be active long enough to actuate the going train.

Here is what I am looking for in the bottom plot, ignore that I mislabeled the top plots as "100%". How can I accomplish this truncation with a simple chip solution? I do not want a microcontroller involved.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use three standard logic ICs:

- 1x 14-pin 74HCT74 Dual D-Type Flip-Flop
- 1x 16-pin 74HCT4060 14-stage Binary Counter With R-C Oscillator
- 1x 14-pin 74HCT08 Quad AND gate (or equivalent required function)

These are 5 V parts but there are equivalents in other logic families for different supply rails e.g. 74LVC4060 and 74LVC08 for 3.3 V. You can also use a different AND gate IC or diode-AND circuit instead of 74HCT08 to do job, as suitable.

First, use one DFF (D-Type Flip-Flop) in the 74HCT74 to divide the 32.768 kHz square wave down to 16.384 kHz. This is illustrated below (image from [here](https://www.eecs.tufts.edu/%7Edsculley/tutorial/flopsandcounters/flops5.html)).

[image]

The 74HCT4060 14-stage counter IC is shown below (diagram from [datasheet](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT4060.pdf)). Drive its RS input with your 16.384 kHz clock. Ground its MR input and leave its RTC and CTC pins unconnected.

You can now take your waveforms from the 74HCT4060 counter outputs and logically AND them together using the 74HCT08 Quad AND Gate IC:

- For 25% duty cycle, use (Q12 AND Q13)
- For 12.5% duty cycle, use (Q11 AND Q12 AND Q13)

You can connect up two 2-input AND gates in series to produce a 3-input AND gate.

Remember to tie all unused DFF and AND gate inputs to their Vcc.

[image]

Comment: Could I use a SN74LVC1G08-Q1 Single 2-input positive-AND gate from TI? https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g08-q1.pdf?ts=1647267780622&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: @AustinFox, my answer explains the principle so you can select the precise parts and AND circuit you need. Your question doesn't specify voltages, situation, costs, part re-use or anything so part numbers can't be recommended. You can find these easily enough. (Please don't add any info' in more comments, edit it into your question.)

Comment: @AustinFox, incidentally you've accepted this as an answer then retracted it - any particular reason?

Comment: Understood, I retracted the acceptance because of the additional question I added but I see that I should be asking this as a separate circuit construction question one I have more established at a component level, thankyou for your help!

Comment: @AustinFox, you're welcome :-) It should be pretty close to what you want. If you detail your question as asked then I can revise the answer slightly to give you all you'll need for what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Feed 4 Hz into the clock input of a 4017. Feed the 5th output back to MR. 1 Hz, 25% duty cycle available from any of first 4 outputs.

Alternatively, feed 8 Hz into the clock input of a 4017. Feed the 9th output back to MR. 1 Hz, 12.5% duty cycle available from any of first 8 outputs.

Comment: This makes sense too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a separate analog monoatabile flip-flop trigger on rising or falling edge of the 1 Hz signal for any period of length you find suitable.

For 25% duty you can and the top 2 bits of the 32768 Hz counter together, or 3 bits for 12.5% duty.

Comment: Okay, to try and clarify here, right now I have 2^15 Hz, which is divided down by 2^13 to get 4. You are saying that I should add a 3 bit adder chip to count the 4 Hz signal and read the 3rd bit output (_ "bit 3" _ "bit 2" _ "bit 1" _) that would trigger high on every forth count?

Comment: ***use a 2-bit adder and only read the carry-out bit*** which would read high for 1/4 second once every second.

Comment: You did not say that you have already divided the count but in that case just use two bits of your 4 Hz counter then, they are both high for 25% of the time.

Comment: There is no analog monostable flip-flop, flip-flops are digital circuits.

Comment: @Uwe 74LS121 uses external analogue RC components instead of digital counter to generate pulses.