# Frequency division ICs

Tags: clock

I am working on a watch circuit that I would like to be more accurate than normal. I am using a 32768 Hz temperature-compensated crystal oscillator. I intend to cut that down to 1 Hz with D-type flip flops, and then 1/60 Hz with a MOD60 counter.

I've seen it done using one 74HCT4060 chained with one 74HCT4013, but I was looking around and found the [74ACT16374](https://www.ti.com/product/74ACT16374) 16 D-flip flop chip from TI.

Can this single chip accomplish the same "divide a clock frequency by 2^15" function as the combined 74XX chips above?

Does anyone have another one-chip solution to divide the 32kHz clock down to 1 Hz in one chip?

For reference this is sort of a continuation of this [previous discussion.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/612012/simple-clock-division)

Comment: To make a frequency divider from type D flip flops, you'll have to feed the data in to each stage from its own _inverted_ data out, and you'll have to clock each stage with the _output from the previous stage._ I don't see how the 74ACT16374 chip will be much help there, especially since the 16 flip flops are organized as two groups of eight with each group having its own _common clock._

Comment: These day a common response would be 'use a CPLD' for which counters are *the* benchmark application. Otherwise the 74LV8154 is a dual 16-bit counter that could do the job

Comment: @SolomonSlow with the 16374 you could probably sythesize a *synchronous* counter (using an unspecified amount of combinatorial logic). Clearly not what the op wants, however

Comment: Could you please provide more information on how to use SN74LV8154N as a divider to get the 1 Hz I am looking for? I am confused by the use of Y BUS outputs. In the cd4060 I can simply pull the divided signal from "QXX" but how do I read a divided frequency from the Y BUS?

Comment: Use a microcontroller. Pretty much any ATtiny, PIC10F, or similar 6 or 8-pin device could do this with a couple of lines of code - either using a hardware timer module (preferable) or just counting the pulses in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1) 74ACT16374 cannot be used as a single-chip clock divider**

To make a ripple counter out of DFFs, each DFF must toggle when clocked by latching in the inverse of its output (see [diagram](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/A-4-bit-ripple-counter-circuit-The-output-of-one-flip-flop-clocks-the-next-one-hence_fig6_238687766) below). The '16374 contains 16 individual D-type Flip-Flops (DFFs) but no output inverters.

[image]

**(2) One-chip solution for 32768 Hz-> 1 Hz using the 20-pin 74LV5184**

The 74LV5184 runs off a 2..5.5 V supply and will divide your 32768 Hz `clock` down to 1 Hz and others when connected as below (mod'd diagram from [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lv8154-ep.pdf)).

*(I see you've since added a [separate question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/612253/how-to-use-74lv8154-to-divide-32-khz-clock-input/612263) specifically on this IC. I've kept this answer since it lists options.)*

[image]

**(3) One-chip solution for 32768 Hz-> 1/60th Hz using a CPLD**

You can use a cheap CPLD, free development software and about twenty lines of VHDL to do the division to 1/60th in one chip.

The suitability of that depends on so many factors individual to yourself: cost, power consumption, availability, practicality, volumes, likelihood of changes etc. Assessing that fully is beyond the scope of the site.

Comment: Very helpful response, I feel like I am getting a much better grasp on things. Can I ask why I would use a CPLD as opposed to a microcontroller like a seeeduino xiao or some ATtiny chip?

Comment: @AustinFox, you're welcome :-) A question for you: do you have a clear understanding of the distinct and total difference between a CPLD/FPGA and a computing device like an MCU? They contain totally different circuitry (A: a CPLD/FPGA contains a user-designed digital logic circuit, whereas an MCU contains a CPU core that executes a sequential program instructions from memory.)

Comment: I believe I have the general "first paragraph of Wiki" understanding of the differences. I have experience with Arduino but none with CPLD or FPGA. I would presume that a microcontroller is a "Jack of all trades" but is sequential and slow, and CPLD/FPGA are better for high frequency or parallel operations. Based on this, it seem like 32k Hz is within the frequency scope of a simple microcontroller, and the counting operation is within its memory capabilities. I would guess that a microcontroller would be the best fit to perform a fin ->1 Hz or fin -> 1/60 Hz division.

Comment: @AustinFox, an MCU's definitely not the best technical fit. The design needs a digital logic circuit and that's exactly what CPLD/FPGA are. If you're saying you understand MCUs but don't understand CPLD/FPGA so you're going for the familiar one just because it's familiar, that's your prerogative. Hence my answer's point about factors. But it doesn't make it a technically better selection. It's harder to make it reliably do the job, easy in VHDL. (We can go to chat if you'd like a longer talk on the general CPLD/FPGA vs MCU subject, rather than in comments here.)

Comment: I am more than happy to learn if another solution is technically better, I have a mechanical engineering background and was not even aware of CPLD/FPGA until recently. This project I am working on is completely about learning electronics and expressing my artsy side with a wrist watch. At the moment I should try and learn more about CPLD/FPGA implementation and if I have additional concerns I will message you. In the mean time I think your answer has satisfied the original question so I will close the post. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with using CD4000 logic family for this. In fact, that's precisely the logic family you would want, because any more modern faster logic family will emit RFI interference like crazy - it's way too fast for this use. You don't want 74HCT4xxx family as it's much faster than CD4000.

For details of such circuits, and the general overview of the 4000 logic family, I highly recommend [The CMOS Cookbook](https://www.tinaja.com/ebooks/cmoscb.pdf).

Comment: Interesting point, and good to know!  I am not sure I care about the RFI interference as much as I care about saving space with the 74LV5184 over using two 40XX.