# How to use 74LV8154 to divide 32 kHz clock input

Tags: clock

I am trying to divide a 32768 Hz clock input down to 1 Hz using only one chip because space is a concern. I was recommended to use a 74LV8154 from TI but I cannot find any examples of how to implement this chip. I am relatively inexperienced (mechanical engineer) and I am stumped by the use of Y Bus outputs on this chip. I am used to seeing QXX outputs on chips like CD4060 where I can just "read" the divisions at each Q output. How do I get the signals I want from 74LV8154? I may also need to read other frequencies like 2 Hz or 4 Hz or 8 Hz, can this be read simultaneously to the 1 Hz or can you only read one frequency at a time?

Comment: the Y outputs are simply three state buffers, controlled via the 4 multiplexer selection inputs !GAL, !GAU, !GBL and !GBU. I.e. if any one of the active-low selection inputs is active, the buffer outputs are active; otherwise they are high impedance. The !GAL/!GAU/!GBL/!GBU inputs select the upper/lower 8 bits of one of two 16-bit counters to be output on the Y0 - Y7.

Comment: @StarCat With one caveat (which I myself just noticed) - RCLK is needed to load the counters into the output registers upstream of the mux.

Comment: @nanofarad, good point.

Comment: Why are you a miser for space? Can you use SMT?  Why not the conventional binary counter with 8,4,2 Hz and dual FF for quadrature 1 Hz

Comment: This is for-fun hobby quartz wrist watch project I am developing. I am using it as a learning platform to educate myself on electrical engineering and an artistic outlet. SMT is definitely an option.  I am trying to avoid conventional FF binary counters like the 4060 because I am seeking a smaller package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To divide your 32768 Hz `clock` down to 1 Hz and other frequencies, connect it as below.

The diagram is modified from that in the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lv8154-ep.pdf).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The 74LV8154 has two counters, each 16-bits wide (counting 0-65535). The GAL/GAU/GBL/GBU allow selecting the upper or lower half of one of these two counters and outputting it to the eight shared output pins.

To divide by 32768, you only need one of these two counters:

- Hold CCLR high to de-assert the 'clear counter' signal
- Connect your input clock to CLKA.
- Connect CLKB to ground, and hold CLKBEN high to disable counter B.
- Pull GAU low and GAL/GBU/GBL high, to output the high byte of counter A on the outputs.
- Connect your input clock to RCLK to load the counter into the output registers automatically.
- With GAU low, Y0 has clk/512, Y1 has clk/1024, ..., Y5 has clk/16384 (2 Hz), Y6 has clk/32768 (i.e. 1 Hz). These are all separate pins and can be read simultaneously.

  - To be precise: Y6 toggles at 2 Hz, so it completes a whole low-high transition in one second.